Angular Datepicker formats two digit dates into literal year
For example, if I type the date 17/11/24, the date will become 17/11/0024
Why is this happening? I've noticed that if I import MatNativeDateModule, this doesn't happen, but then the date is in an american format.
My code is the following:
I've tried my best to recreate the issue on stackblitz
https://angular-2qxvhtpt.stackblitz.io
Obviously there's something going on with the datepicker when the user types a date in that's resulting in two digit years being off by 2000 years.
Does anyone know what might be causing this?
